# Sharing Session Across Tasks in WebApi

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-web-api2

I have a client program which sends off to a webapi and gets a websocket back.

Once hooked up I then send off a second request to the api to start a number of tests.

The webapi then hooks into the websocket as well. sending messages as it completes the tasks. I do this using System.Net.Websockets.ClientWebSocket

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var socket = new ClientWebSocket();
string wsUri = "wss://localhost:44301/api/v1/devices/registerForSocket";
await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(wsUri), cts.Token);

RunTests(deviceid, socket, cts);
```

Now I need to add the ability for the client to also poll for a current progress update. Basically, this will be a bool which is set to false when a process is being run and then reverted back to true once its finished.

Now to do this I will have to run a seperate ClientWebSocket for receiving the "PROGRESS" messages.

However, how can I share the progress between the two tasks? Is this be best way to go about it?